# Xbox One Bluetooth controller Connection problems 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, xbox-one

I´m quite new to Linux/Ubuntu so sorry if this is an easy question. I read that the Bluetooth connection works "out of the box" in 18.04. My problem is that When I try to connect it keeps connecting then disconnecting then connecting etc.. I tried some other solutions but none have solved the problem.

Edit:
lsusb:

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57eb Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

dmesg|tail gives me this following:

[  630.381504] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Microsoft

[  630.381510] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 3032534830313633363532373332

[  631.098180] input: Microsoft X-Box One S pad as /devices/pci0000:00
/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input19

[  631.098530] usbcore: registered new interface driver xpad

[  637.989971] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)

[  641.685829] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 4

[  653.989970] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)

[  667.042896] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)

[  682.988896] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)

[  698.988994] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)

Comment: May i ask you to show the logs -
`dmesg|tail` &

`lsusb`

Comment: Enter command one by one, after plugging in the receiver.
And type `bluetooth -d -n` to check if any device is detected?

Comment: You very likely need to connect your controller via USB to a Windows install, and update the firmware.

Comment: It says the firmware is up to date. It was also working with xubuntu.